# Possible to track where image has been requested from?

Tags: node.js, tracking

I want to track image views when it originates from a particular domain. For example, I have an image in a web page at exmaple.com. But this can be shared on Facebook or something, which for my current usecase, I dont want to track. Isit possible to do this? I am using a simple server setup with NodeJS.

I looked into the request parameter and found that the host parameter is always set to the server hosting the image ... not where the image request comes from. Isit possible to get that info?

**UPDATE**

Actually `myserver.com/image.jpg` does not point to a jpg file in this case, it actually ends up in a nodejs request, where I check to see if the image exists, if so I increment the view and return the image.

```
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
    res.end(data);
```

Ok I was looking at `req.headers` and the output looks like:

```
{ host: 'localhost:5000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  cookie: 's_nr=1418800700375; _ga=GA1.1.934001987.1419587449' }
```

The problem is the host seems to be always set to the nodeJS server. So even if the image is requested from example.com, the host is NOT example.com.

Comment: You can serve image not as a content, but with request and track your parameters there

Comment: Erm what do you mean? Do you mean include some query params or something? If so wont facebook also include those params when they extract the image?

Comment: You mean the HTTP referer?

Comment: No, you will have a dedicated url to serve the images like `myapp.com/images?imageid=something`, you will set up your server to response an image for the request, so that you can see where the request is coming from inside your request handler

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, yes unless I understood the term wrong. Suppose the example.com has HTML like `<img src="http://myserver.com/image.jpg">`, I want the value of `example.com`. I hope thats what a referrer mean?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin, I believe thats what I have currently, see update. Basically, when I look into the `request.headers.host` it appears to always refer to the nodeJS server, not where I expect the request to have come from

Comment: @JiewMeng yep, that's why I meant. If you show the image on your page, then the referrer will be your server, if someone from another host will request it (like facebook crawler) the the host will change

Comment: The HTTP `Host` header is the server the request is to (to allow name-based virtual hosting).  The `Referer` header is the page the request is being made from (either as a clicked link or an embedded resource such as an image).  These are different.  You want `Referer`.  I don't know node.js, so that's as much help as I can be.